# Distance between 2 emas of previous five candles

Tags: pine-script

I am calculating the distance between two emas and I can retrieve the value into the dist variable.

```
fast = ta.ema(close, 50)
slow = ta.ema(close, 200)
plot(fast, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title='Fast')
plot(slow, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='Slow')

longEntry = ta.crossover(fast, slow)
shortEntry = ta.crossunder(fast, slow)

dist = fast - slow
```

Crossover return a negative value (ex: -1.985)
Crossunder returns a positive value (ex: 1.985)

I would like to check if the value of the 5 or X previous candles have a dist value which is higher than the actual value. If it is possible, how?

Thanks in advance for your assistance, cheers, Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ta.highestbars](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dhighestbars) for Highest value of "dist" offset for 5 bars back.

Something like that

```
distPrv = ta.highestbars(dist, 5)
```

Then you can compare both values, and with a [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) create the trigger you need